# R - Merging dataframes by two columns with additional "between values" condition?

Tags: r, dataframe, merge

I have two dataframes, as follows:

Dataframe A:

```
code1 code2 element1 from to
c1a    c2a     e1a     1    15
c1a    c2a     e1b     17   50
c1a    c2b     e1c     14   67
c1b    c2c     e1d     1    20
c1b    c2d     e1e    40   60
```

Dataframe B:

```
code1 code2 element2 number
c1a    c2a     e2a    7
c1a    c2a     e2b    10
c1a    c2a     e2c    35
```

I basically need to join them if `from =< number <= to`, to obtain something like:

RESULT DATAFRAME

(Fragment, I don't have enough mock up data. I want this merge for both *full* dataframes A and B).

```
code1 code2 element1 element2 from   to   number
c1a    c2a     e1a    e2a      1     15     7
c1a    c2a     e1a    e2b      1     15     10
c1a    c2a     e1b    e2c      17    50     35
```

I can do this with a for loop, and manually check, but I was wondering if there is a more "elegant" way of doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can join data and then `filter` the values which are in range.

You can do this in `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
left_join(B, A, by = c('code1', 'code2')) %>% 
    filter(number >= from & number <= to)

#  code1 code2 element2 number element1 from to
#1   c1a   c2a      e2a      7      e1a    1 15
#2   c1a   c2a      e2b     10      e1a    1 15
#3   c1a   c2a      e2c     35      e1b   17 50
```

Or in base R :

```
subset(merge(B, A, by = c('code1', 'code2')), number >= from & number <= to)
```

Comment: Why the filter? If I just do the merge like that, it doesn't necessarily align element1 and element 2. It just duplicates rows.

Comment: Check the output of `merge(A, B, by = c('code1', 'code2'))` it gives you all the rows with all the values `filter` is needed to remove the rows which are not in-between `from` and `to`.

Comment: It doesn't make sense, I don't need a subset. I need the whole thing. Otherwise, I need to run a filter per each combination of  code1 and code2

Comment: If you check the answer I am already joining by `c('code1', 'code2')` so you don't have to run filter per each combination. I am not sure what is confusing for you.It works for the example you have shared, if you have a more complex situation please update your post accordingly where the above answer fails.

Comment: Okay, I was finally able to try it, but the subsetting is not working. It doesn't filter anything =S

Comment: How is your actual data different than the example you have shared?

Comment: No sorry, had a different issue going on. Fixed it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Here's one using `fuzzyjoin::fuzzy_inner_join`.
I understand from your output that besides the criteria for `from =< number <= to`, you would like to join by `code1` and `code2`.

1. Join `code1` and `code2` by equality
2. Join `from` to `number` by the first inequality, i.e. `from <= number`
3. Join `to` to `number` by the second inequality, i.e. `number <= to`

The thing with `fuzzy_join` is that they output all columns in both dataframes.

-

```
library(fuzzyjoin)
fuzzy_inner_join(
      df_A, df_B,
      by = c(
        "code1" = "code1",
        "code2" = "code2",
        "from" = "number",
        "to" = "number"),
      match_fun = c(
        "code1" = function(l, r) l == r,
        "code2" = function(l, r) l == r,
        "from" = function(l, r) l <= r,
        "to" = function(l, r) r <= l))

# code1.x code2.x element1 from to code1.y code2.y element2 number
# 1     c1a     c2a      e1a    1 15     c1a     c2a      e2a      7
# 2     c1a     c2a      e1a    1 15     c1a     c2a      e2b     10
# 3     c1a     c2a      e1b   17 50     c1a     c2a      e2c     35
```

**data**

```
df_A <- structure(list(code1 = c("c1a", "c1a", "c1a", "c1b", "c1b"), 
    code2 = c("c2a", "c2a", "c2b", "c2c", "c2d"), element1 = c("e1a", 
    "e1b", "e1c", "e1d", "e1e"), from = c(1L, 17L, 14L, 1L, 40L
    ), to = c(15L, 50L, 67L, 20L, 60L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -5L))

df_B <- structure(list(code1 = c("c1a", "c1a", "c1a"), code2 = c("c2a", 
"c2a", "c2a"), element2 = c("e2a", "e2b", "e2c"), number = c(7L, 
10L, 35L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L))
```

Comment: I get `Error in mf(rep(u_x, n_y), rep(u_y, each = n_x), ...) : could not find function "mf"` when I try to run this.

Comment: Have you installed `fuzzyjoin`?